# Is it possible to query mailbox statistics for mailbox that has been put on litigation hold then the associated user account deleted in office 365 PS

Tags: powershell, office365, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to retrieve mailbox statistics for a mailbox that I put on litigation hold, then deleted its associated account in office 365. I know the mailbox is inactive state.

Is it possible to query mailbox statistics for mailbox that has been put on litigation hold then the associated user account deleted in office 365, I need to achieve this using powershell.

My PowerShell script and the error that is getting.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $inactive = Get-Mailbox -InactiveMailboxOnly
PS C:\Windows\system32> $user = $inactive.SamAccountName
PS C:\Windows\system32> $mailstat = Get-MailboxStatistics $user
The specified mailbox Identity:"$VLHCB0-O2T8NUTCI12G" doesn't exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-MailboxStatistics], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=AM9PR09MB4882,RequestId=97a79e6b-77a1-48f8-9a1a-32ada94a0f5a,TimeStamp=4/14/2022 6:49:24 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundExceptio
   n] FE6CA880,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.MapiTasks.GetMailboxStatistics
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

I get the same errors above, when i pass each accepted identity parameter value for `get-mailboxstatistics cmdlet`

According to microsoft, this are the accepted values for identity parameter, when using `get-mailboxstatistics`:

```
Name
Alias
Distinguished name (DN)
Canonical DN
Domain\Username
Email address
GUID
LegacyExchangeDN
SamAccountName
User ID or user principal name (UPN)
```

Comment: `Get-Mailbox -InactiveMailboxOnly`, does this only get you a single user? If so, you should be able to pipe directly to `Get-MailboxStatistics`.

Comment: I'm getting errors when i do that even for a single mailbox. I have 7125 users in the tenant to evaluate if there mailbox is inactive or not, if its inactive then grab its mailbox statistics.

Comment: This is the error `The specified mailbox Identity:"Soft Deleted Objects\TUser" doesn't exist.`